# Nasm is not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: gcc, nasm

I am working on a java compiler project coded in python open source github link ishttps://github.com/abhigarg-iitk/java_compiler
this compileris working and converting java file into assembly language but nasm and gcc not working. I have installed nasm already and still getting the same error message.[Nasm errror on command prompt1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9xe2.png)

[Nasm error on command prompt 2[][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyBVe.png)

Comment: You probably haven't added the nasm and gcc directories to your PATH. By the way: that assembly code looks intended for 32-bit Linux, so you wouldn't be able to run it on Windows even if you managed to assemble and link it.

Comment: @Michael so if i will run this project on linux platform and install nasm ....will it run properly? I have to submit this as my final year project in less than 5 days...please help

Comment: I have never used that Java compiler you're using, so I have no idea if it will work. I'm just saying that it will almost certainly _not_ work on Windows, since the generated code looks like it's intended for Linux.